# How to prevent person who commit to a PR from merging on Github?

Tags: github, pull-request

Person A creates a Pull Request and person B commits to the PR but person A is not able to approve/merge their PR, but person B can approve/merge person A's PR even though they committed/changes to it.

How can I block person from approving/merging their own commits even though its not their PR?

[image]

What would pre-received hook for it on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the following policies under Settings - Branches. You will have to create a policy for the branch you want to protect, generally that will be `main`.

- <kbd>✓</kbd> Require pull request before merging

  - <kbd>✓</kbd> Require approvals
  - <kbd>✓</kbd> Require approval of the most recent push
  - <kbd>✓</kbd> Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed

This combination of policies should not allow the last pusher to approve their own changes.

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/github-githubs-require-approval-of-the-most-recent-push-policy/
- https://www.legitsecurity.com/blog/bypassing-github-required-reviewers-to-submit-malicious-code
- https://medium.com/boostsecurity/slsa-dip-source-of-the-problem-a1dac46a976
- https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-new-branch-protections-last-pusher-and-locked-branch/

To create this policy, go to the repository, open the ⚙️ settings.

[image]

Go to Branches:

[image]

Click <kbd>Add branch protection rule</kbd> (or edit an exiting one) and turn on the abovementioned policies:

[image]

Comment: Where can I set that in Github settings?

Comment: You didn't answer the question; I didn't ask about PR request. I asked if a PR is open; and someone makes a commit; they shouldn't be able to merge

Comment: sorry I was refering to another person who just deleted their comment. How can I change the setting on Github for that?

Comment: Screenshots added above.

Comment: Yes I have all those checks except for `Require Approval of the most recent reviewable push` ...that is not in my Github setting. I wonder if it has to do with versioning.

Comment: Are you on GitHub Enterprise Server?

Comment: yes I am but on Github version 3.9

Comment: Looks like this will be part of 3.10 https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.10/admin/release-notes

Comment: Yes its not released yet